# Bound on the number of connected components of a linear algebraic group $G<\mathrm{SL}_n$?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-groups

Let $G<\mathrm{SL}_n$ be a linear algebraic group defined over a field. Is there a bound on the number of connected components of $G$ in terms of $n$ alone?

(The bound will evidently not be any smaller than $n!$. It is also clear why we are requiring $G<\mathrm{SL}_n$ and not $G<\mathrm{GL}_n$: the variety $\det(g)^k-1$ has $k$ connected components with each connected component being of the form $\det(g) = \omega$, $\omega$ a $k$th degree of unity. Clearly we cannot bound $k$ in terms of $n$.)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the definition of 'linear algebraic group'.  It seems to me that the subgroup $G_k\subset\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ defined by the equations $g\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}g$ and $g^k=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ has at least $k$ components.  Is this $G_k$ not 'linear algebraic'?

Comment: Maybe you want to work modulo abelian normal subgroups, as in Jordan's Theorem and its variants.

Comment: @RobertBryant Right, that's the general sort of thing I wanted to avoid (roots of unity) and your example makes it clear that requiring $G<\mathrm{SL}_n$ is not enough. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveBenson Well, Jordan's theorem is not true in characteristic $\ne 0$, at least not without additional conditions. Larsen-Pink amounts to a version that works for arbitrary characteristic. I suppose one cannot really do better than that?

Comment: I suppose any finite subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ can be seen as "linear algebraic" in so far as it is a zero-dimensional (non-irreducible) variety - and the finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ for $K$ of characteristic $\ne 0$ are harder to classify than for $K\ne 0$. Then one could try yo define more complicated examples by considering the product $\Gamma\cdot G$ for $G$ a linear algebraic group normalized by $\Gamma$. So the answer to my question has to be "no".

Comment: If one allows a dependence on the degree of $G$ as a variety, then bounding the number of connected components of $G$ becomes trivial (it is bounded by the degree of $G$).

Comment: In all of these examples, the exact sequence $1\to G_0\to G\to \Gamma\to 1$ splits, i.e., we can really see the quotient $G/G_0$ as a finite subgroup of $G$. What would be an example of a sequence (with $\Gamma$ big and nasty) in which this does not happen?

Comment: It might be worth noting that $GL_n$ embeds into $SL_{n+1}$ via $g \to \begin{pmatrix}g&0\\0&det(g)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$, so your $GL$ example is also an $SL$ example.

Comment: Right, thanks. If all examples split, then one could deal with the matter by Larsen-Pink. I now wonder whether there are simple examples where the exact sequence does not split, i.e., where we don't really have a finite group that we can deal with separately.